# Android Stand alone compiler getting openssl error

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, openssl

I tried to compile sofia-sip native library using Android NDK.

getting this error always:

> /home/umn/android/android-ndk-r7c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld:
>   cannot find -lssl collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Sure. Did you build OpenSSL? Where is libssl?